# NFS mount becoming unbearably slow over time with high number of test_stateid RPC calls

Tags: nfs

At work, we have several workstations in a computer pool with user homes on our central NAS, mounted via NFS. We're facing the issue that file access on these shares sometimes becomes unbearably slow after a while (hours, days, ...). Rebooting the client machine resolves the issue. We couldn't figure out what is causing this, but observed the following using our [netdata](https://github.com/netdata/netdata) monitoring.

[image]

Apparently, there is a high number of `test_stateid` calls going on. There is also a kernel process with 100 % CPU utilization (on a single core).

For comparison, this is what it looks like on a machine where NFS is still responsive:

[image]

We also observed that after unmounting the volume (`umount -l`), the number of `test_stateid` calls increases even further (from ~ 300/sec to ~ 3000/sec).

We also observe thousand of these in the kernel logs:

```
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: nfs41_handle_sequence_flag_errors: "redacted.example.org" (client ID 5709396434020000) flags=0x00000040
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: --> nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0001 highest_used=0 max_slots=10
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: <-- nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0003 highest_used=1 slotid=1
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: nfs4_free_slot: slotid 1 highest_used_slotid 0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: nfs41_sequence_process: Error 0 free the slot 
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: nfs4_free_slot: slotid 0 highest_used_slotid 4294967295
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: --> nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0000 highest_used=4294967295 max_slots=10
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: <-- nfs4_alloc_slot used_slots=0001 highest_used=0 slotid=0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: encode_sequence: sessionid=1681459543:564:96:0 seqid=176335892 slotid=0 max_slotid=0 cache_this=1
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_type: type=00
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_change: change attribute=108
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_size: file size=149204
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_fsid: fsid=(0x0/0x0)
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_fileid: fileid=0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_fs_locations: fs_locations done, error = 0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_mode: file mode=00
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_nlink: nlink=1
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_rdev: rdev=(0x0:0x0)
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_space_used: space used=0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_time_access: atime=0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_time_metadata: ctime=1700570570
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_time_modify: mtime=1700570570
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_attr_mounted_on_fileid: fileid=0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_getfattr_attrs: xdr returned 0
Dez 04 10:40:22 myhost01 kernel: decode_getfattr_generic: xdr returned 0
```

Any ideas on how to further debug this?

The workstations are on Ubuntu 22.04 with kernel 6.2.0-37-generic.